# Saving every nth packet from a UDP stream

Tags: python, udp, python-multithreading, mpeg2-ts

I am parsing embedded KLV data in an MPEG-TS video stream sent to a UDP port from a UAV to use in a real time map. I am getting 25 packets per second (tied to the video frame rate) at the moment and can save all of this data but I want to only save the data once a second. Every 40ms is too much. I have attempted using threading to run  2 functions. One to get the data and write to a global variable and one to read that variable every second and print/save.

```
#setup code (UDP socket etc)

#global variable for KLV metadata
metadata = {}

#Function to parse KLV data from UDP Stream using klvdata module
def getData():
    while True:
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(2048)
        for packet in klvdata.StreamParser(data):
            global metadata
            metadata=packet.MetadataList()
           
           
#Prints selected keys at 1 sec intervals. Add more keys as required           
def printData():
     while True:
        global metadata
        time.sleep(1)
        
        long = round(float(metadata[14][3]),6)
        print(f"Sensor Longitude: {long}")
        
        lat = round(float(metadata[13][3]),6)
        print(f"Sensor Latitude: {lat}")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Thread(target=getData)
    t1.start()
            
    t2 = Thread(target=printData)
    t2.start()
```

This has had mixed success. If the UDP stream is not running I get a key error as the dict is empty and the while loop in the printData func is infinite regardless of new data or not. I understand both of errors and why they happen. What I am wondering is if there is a better way to do this than the path I'm on now.

Thanks

Comment: there is good rule to to put `global` at the beginning of function. You have to use it inly once in file - you don't have to use it many times inside `while`-loop

Comment: if you get kye error then you can use `try/except` to catch it or use `if key in dict:` to run code only when there is key in dict. If you have list then you can use `if len(list) > index:` to run code when exists `list[index]`

Comment: if you want to stop writing when there is no new data then maybe use some variable to control it - like `if new_data is True: ...` OR use number or date_time to control if there is new data. `If new_number > old_number: ... write data ... ; old_number = new_number`

Comment: at start I would use `metadata = None` and then I could check `if metadata is not None: ... write data ...` . And when there is no new data then I would set again `metadata = None` to stop writing the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works so far but I will test more.

```
#global variable for KLV metadata
metadata = None

#Function to parse KLV data from UDP Stream using klvdata module
def getData():
    global metadata
    while True:
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(2048)
        for packet in klvdata.StreamParser(data):
            metadata=packet.MetadataList()
           
           
           
#Prints selected keys at 1 sec intervals. Add more keys as required           
def printData():
    global metadata
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if metadata is not None:
            long = round(float(metadata[14][3]),6)
            print(f"Sensor Longitude: {long}")
        
            lat = round(float(metadata[13][3]),6)
            print(f"Sensor Latitude: {lat}")

            metadata = None
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but I would use `metadata = None` and `if metadata is not None:` to control if there is new data or not.

```
metadata = None

def getData():
    global metadata # need it because you assign value to variable
    
    while True:
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(2048)
        for packet in klvdata.StreamParser(data):
            metadata = packet.MetadataList()            
        # end of data
        metadata = None            
           
def printData():
    #global metadata # no need it when you only read data from variable
    
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

        if metadata is not None:         
            long = round(float(metadata[14][3]), 6)
            print(f"Sensor Longitude: {long}")
        
            lat = round(float(metadata[13][3]), 6)
            print(f"Sensor Latitude: {lat}")
```

But I'm not sure if this not need to lock `metadata` because one process may read `long`,`lat` when other process may assing `metadata = None` and this can make problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I ended up tweaking your code slightly and setting metadata = none at the end of the printData function.

Comment: instead of in the getData function. I had to reinstate the `global metadata` as well.

Comment: you could describe all changes in your answer and then you could mark it as accepted.